# Could someone check the Minimax Algorithm correctly implemented?

Tags: python, algorithm, ai

I'm working on AI tic-tac-toe that computer make a move and I wanted to know that I correctly implemented the minimax algorithm. Please someone check my code to identify a problem or any kind of bug. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I wanted to know that my code is correctly running the minimax algorithm according to this image.

[test-cases-for-tic-tac-toe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98HtW.png)

```
from math import inf as infinity

def winner(game, turn):
    win_game = [
        [game[0][0], game[0][1], game[0][2]],
        [game[1][0], game[1][1], game[1][2]],
        [game[2][0], game[2][1], game[2][2]],
        [game[0][0], game[1][0], game[2][0]],
        [game[0][1], game[1][1], game[2][1]],
        [game[0][2], game[1][2], game[2][2]],
        [game[0][0], game[1][1], game[2][2]],
        [game[2][0], game[1][1], game[0][2]],
    ]
    if [turn, turn, turn] in win_game:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def draw(game):
    """ Check whether the board is full """
    counter = 0
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if game[i][j] == "X" or game[i][j] == "O":
                counter+=1
    return counter == 9


def game_over(game, turn):
    return winner(game, turn) or draw(game)


def available_moves(game):
    cell = []
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if not(game[i][j] == "X" or game[i][j] == "O"):
                cell.append([i, j])
    return cell


def minimax(game, turn):
    if winner(game, "X"):
        return 1
    elif winner(game, "O"):
        return -1
    elif draw(game):
        return 0

    moves = available_moves(game)
    print(moves)

    if turn == "X":
        value = -infinity
        for move in moves:
            tmp = game[:][:]
            tmp[move[0]][move[1]] = "X"
            value = max(value, minimax(game, "O"))
            tmp[move[0]][move[1]] = None
            x, y = move[0], move[1]
    else:
        value = infinity
        for move in moves:
            tmp = game[:][:]
            tmp[move[0]][move[1]] = "O"
            value = min(value, minimax(game, "X"))
            tmp[move[0]][move[1]] = None
            x, y = move[0], move[1]
    return value


if __name__ == '__main__':


    game = [
        ["O", None, None],
        ["O", "X", "X"],
        [None, "O", "X"]]



    print(minimax(game, "X"))
```

Comment: Hi, sadly we only review working code. I encourage you to check the Help Center to see what kind of questions you may ask here :)

Comment: I have rolled-back your question to the original.  On Code Review, you cannot change your question once it has been answered, as doing so can invalidate any answers which have already been given.  Code Review is also not for assistance locating and fixing bugs in code; it is for reviewing working code.  A review may discover an previously unknown bug, but the code must be working to the best of your knowledge prior to posting it.

Answer (score 3):

`tmp = game[:][:]` is not doing what you think it is doing.  `game[:]` returns a slice of all the rows of `game` (so a list of columns).  To that, you apply the slice operator `[:]`, which takes the slice of the row list (of columns), and returns a row list (of columns).  In short, `game[:]` is the same as `game[:][:]`, which is the same as `game[:][:][:][:][:]`.

In particular, `tmp` is list which contains references to the **same** column lists as `game`, so `tmp[row][col]` accesses exactly the same entry as `game[row][col]`.  You have not created a temporary copy of `game`; you have created a copy of references to the same column list objects.

As such, you can remove `tmp`, and just set `game[row][col]` directly, and set it back to `None` like you are doing via `tmp`.

---

The code `x, y = move[0], move[1]` seems to be useless, since `x` and `y` are never used.

---

The `minimax()` function returns the best possible outcome for that player, but doesn’t return the move that corresponds to that outcome.  “You have a guaranteed winning move, but I’m not going to tell you what it is.”

You might want to return the move that corresponds to that outcome.

Comment: But i have one problem now when I tested more.

Comment: I update my quesiton. Please check my code @AJNeufeld